# GetSaveAsFilename only showing every other variable value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable (`MyFile`) that stores a filename based on certain parameters. It is storing the values just fine (as the `msgbox` function shows each of the 4 names) but, when I put it in the `Application.GetSaveAsFilename(MyFile)` function only every other filename is shown when the dialog opens.

The Code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Customers() As String
    Dim STD, LTD, LIFE, FMLA As Boolean
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim i, c, n As Integer
    i = 15
    c = 0
    n = 0

    Range("C15").End(xlDown).Activate
    Dim r As String
    r = ActiveCell.Row

    For i = 15 To r
        STD = False
        LTD = False
        LIFE = False
        FMLA = False

        If ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Hidden = False Then
            Dim loc As String
            loc = "C" & i
            Range(loc).Activate
            ReDim Customers(c)
            Customers(c) = ActiveCell.Value
            Dim MyFile As String

            If Range("Z" & i).Value <> "" Then
                STD = True
            End If
            If Range("AA" & i).Value <> "" Then
                LTD = True
            End If
            If Range("AB" & i).Value <> "" Then
                FMLA = True
            End If
            If Range("AC" & i).Value <> "" Then
                LIFE = True
            End If

            MyFile = Customers(c)

            If STD = True Then
                MyFile = MyFile & " - STD"
            End If
            If LTD = True Then
                MyFile = MyFile & " - LTD"
            End If
            If LIFE = True Then
                MyFile = MyFile & " - Life"
            End If
            If FMLA = True Then
                MyFile = MyFile & " - FMLA"
            End If

            MsgBox (MyFile) 
            FilePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(MyFile)

            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please post the code too?  That's a big help in diagnosing the problem.  Also see this: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Just added the code

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. The variable held names of companies, some with periods in their name (such as X, Inc.) which was causing the MyFile variable not to populate.